# How can I embed a video encoded in VP9 / H.265 in HTML5?

Tags: html

I'm encoding 4k videos in VP9 / H.265 and would like to stream them to a browser. 
How can I do this in a way that it's supported across the maximal number of browsers?

Comment: I don't get the downvotes, this is a good question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe vp9 will work natively in FF and chrome since over 6 months (FF, chrome longer).
There are as of yet no plugins for IE and certainly no native support.

Hevc (h.265) have no native support anywhere but there are plugins from divx.

So your best bet is to detect capabilities with html5 with vp9 and then have fallback to mp4 (html5) and then have continued fallback to flash (possibly mp4).

So in summary, there is no way to deliver only h.265 and/or vp9. The best you can do is deliver vp9 to about 50% of the worlds population and have fallback for the rest.